# how to control position of figures in LaTeX?

Tags: floats

I have 10 figures. I want to place 8 on one page and rest of the two on next page.
I am using the code

```
    \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(5,3.5)



 \put(2.5,-0.5){$t$}
\put(-1,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig1.eps}}
\put(4,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig2.eps}}
 \put(-1,-4){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig3.eps}}
    \put(4,-4){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig4.eps}}
     \put(-1,-8){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig5.eps}}
        \put(4,-8){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig6.eps}}
         \put(-1,-12){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig7.eps}}
            \put(4,-12){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig8.eps}}

\end{picture}


\end{figure}



 \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
    \begin{picture}(5,3.5)



 \put(2.5,-0.5){$t$}
\put(-1,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig9.eps}}
\put(4,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{fig10.eps}}
\end{picture}
\caption{abc}
 \label{figures}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the last two figures are not being pasted on next page, rather they are overlaped to the figures of first page. How to control?

Comment: your negative coordinates are _specifying_ overprinting, why not specify a large enough picture environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your negative coordinates are specifying overprinting, Adding 12 to each y coordinate in the first figure makes a more reasonable layout.

This appears to be a simple rectangular grid, so you don't really need the picture environment and `\put` at all, simply listing the `\includegraphics` would naturally cause them to lay out 2 to a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(5,12)



 \put(2.5,11.5){$t$}
\put(-1,12){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
\put(4,12){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
 \put(-1,8){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \put(4,8){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
     \put(-1,4){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \put(4,4){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
         \put(-1,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
            \put(4,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}

\end{picture}


\end{figure}



 \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
    \begin{picture}(5,3.5)



 \put(2.5,-0.5){$t$}
\put(-1,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
\put(4,0){\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{picture}
\caption{abc}
 \label{figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for making me better understand the concept. I must try it.